# Launchpad EDDSA Key

Tags: apt, ppa, gnupg, openpgp

I'm trying to start a PPA and I understand I need to register my OpenPGP key with Launchpad.

I have had my PGP key on the Ubuntu keyserver for a long time at:

- http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=vindex&search=max+ehrlich&fingerprint=on

But when I try to input the fingerprint, which I am even copying from the Ubuntu keyserver itself, `00F3 CEDB FFB4 1C0F C3B2  CDE6 DC65 E5FD 407D 831A`, Launchpad just complains that it couldn't import.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? My only thought is that it's because I use EDDSA for everything since it's more secure, but since it's somewhat new Launchpad doesn't support it yet.

I've also tried entering the fingerprint of my signing-only subkey and that didn't work either

Comment: your PGP key should probably be in `RSA` or `ECDSA`, not `EDDSA`.  Not sure if the system itself *actually supports* non-standard PGP signatures like `EDDSA` yet.

Comment: Actually, RSA is still the standard for keys, and the industry standard has been 2048bit keys for some time now.  `EdDSA` isn't in itself more or less secure than anything else.  But I've poked the Launchpad gurus to come take a look and maybe provide you with an authoritative answer.  So have some patience :)

Comment: @ThomasWard Thanks for the info, I am no security expert, the only thing I remember is that it's more about key sizes than anything else. I'm also a little fuzzy about PGP vs GPG. EDDSA is still in the early stages for GPG correct? But maybe not yet part of the PGP standard?

Comment: PGP and GPG are the same standard, but different implementations of the PGP standard.  I just write PGP by force of habit.

Comment: As I suspected, and Colin Watson confirmed, EdDSA is not supported by Launchpad at this time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Launchpad does not currently support EdDSA - it currently supports RSA, DSA, and ElGamal key algorithms.

We'd need to make some code changes to add support for EdDSA.  Please [file a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+filebug) requesting it.